# Book: human-centric galaxy

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking to identify a novel or series of books where the human race it at war with an alien race.

As the story (or series) progresses, it turns out that there is only one race of aliens in the galaxy (could potentially be the universe), all alien races are based on "human" stock, humans of earth just being one variation. The galaxy has been seeded with humans by a more ancient race. The race of aliens the human race was originally at war with is a bio-engineered former servitor race.

Edit:
Thank you to those below that have asked for extra details.

I seem to remember that the situation of the seeding of the galaxy with human based intelligence was described to the protagonist at some forum/meeting where they discussed the various differences in the races, extra ribs etc were really superficial variations on a theme.

I also think that the (engineered) alien race at war with the humans of earth is wolf/dog-like, or that is the image I have of them.

I am guessing, but I think I must've read this in the late 90s or 2000s.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book? Also, do you recall any details about the cover?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Something I'm not clear on. Is that "bio-engineered former servitor race" that looks "wolf/dog like" one of those many races in the galaxy that all turn out to be descended from ancient human stock? Or are they an exception to the rule, because they are truly descended from a canine-style race which had no close connection to the modern humans of Planet Earth?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. The race of dog-like aliens at war with the humans from Earth are bio engineered and not descended from a canine-style race, or from human-stock. I think they were engineered as a servitor race to either the progenitors or an older, powerful human race.

Comment: could it be the Lensman series, where humans are at war with Boskone?

Answer (score 2):

Could this be *[Probability Moon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/68322.Probability_Moon)* (2000) by Nancy Kress, the first book in the *[Probability Trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/63708-probability-trilogy)*...?

> Earth is an environmental disaster area when humanity gains new hope: a star gate is discovered in the solar system, built by a long-gone alien race. Earth establishes extrasolar colonies and discovers alien races--including the warlike Fallers, the only spacefaring race besides humans. Mysterious, uncommunicative, and relentlessly bent on humanity's extinction, the Fallers have mastered the star gates, and are closing in on earth.
>
> Dr. Bazargan commands the scientific team sent to a newly discovered world to study its humanoid natives: beings who literally perceive only one reality. To lie is to be unreal--and condemned to death. The humans must flee for their lives across the unknown planet when they and the aliens learn the scientific mission is a lie. It's the cover for a secret military exploration of the moon Tas, which is another artifact of the gate-makers: a superweapon capable of annihilating all life in a star system, and already known to the Fallers.

Searching [a preview of the book](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Probability_Moon/fgSmUhEdo0QC?hl=en&gbpv=0), I found the following extract which closely matches parts of your description:

> Ann Sikorski specialized in the xenobiology of neurosystems. So far, it had been a disappointing field. Through the space tunnels, humans had discovered thirty-six other sentient species, and thirty-five of them had been, in essence, human. They possessed only minor variations in skeletal structure, biochemistry, genome, and neurology. The prevailing theory was something -- or some race -- had seeded the galaxy with a common psuedo-human ancestor, and subsequent evolution had diverged only as various planetary conditions favored.

Comment: Hi. I don't think the book I am looking for is Probability Moon, while there are similarities (body format etc) it seems that in Nancy Kress's book that humans from Earth are the most advanced human species. In the book I am looking for, I think the humans from Earth are the most recent on the interstellar stage. I will be picking up Probability Moon now though, thank you for the introduction.

Answer (score 1):

possibly a little late for your timeframe, but could it be [Dark Space](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23365213-dark-space)

This is a series of books about humanity losing badly in a war against aliens and surviving in a small hidden pocket of space.
As the story progresses it is revealed that there are several factions at play all of which are humans.  The original 'alien' aggressors were humans engineered to survive on harsh planets with the main factions being immortal humans that use cloning to live for ever.

The 'aliens' attacking were described as being more animal like